# Why FIR uses often direct-form instead of transposed-form?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, finite-impulse-response, digital-filters

Even though tranposed-form has less computational burden and memory requirements, why FIR uses mostly direct-form?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont think that df1/df2/tf matters much for a FIR filter. Arithmetic complexity is going to be N mults and N-1 adds. For IIR filters choice of topology is often dictated by numerical considerations.

Comment: Can you show that the transposed form uses fewer computations and less memory than the transversal filter structure?

Comment: This is because the direct form needs memory elements to realize the shift register for x[n] and memory elements to realize the adder trees in the coefficient multipliers, whereas the transposed direct-form can do it with just one kind of memory elements, which realize both at the same time, the shift register as well as the the coefficient-multiplier memories.

Comment: I don't see how memory or computational burden can possibly be reduced, perhaps you could included a diagram of each showing that?

Comment: Are you confusing FIR with IIR perhaps ? Transposed vs direct makes more of a meaningful difference for IIR filters

Comment: I think that this question needs some context. Are you talking about Javascript? C code running on a microcontroller? cpu with SIMD instructions? FPGA? ASIC? Specialized solutions for convolution with long kernels might employ FFTs. Fixed point implementations running on hw with limited multiplication capabilities might use shift operations instead.

Comment: if the implementation preserves bits until quantization **must** occur at the final output, the Direct Form is far simpler than the Transposed Form.  using the transposed form requires that your states have double-wide word widths unless you quantize each of those states back to single width.  but that is more quantization error than if you just add up a bunch of double-wide words and quantize the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how memory or computational burden can possibly be reduced between the two implementations (note this is not implying simplicity, just number of computations required, please read on...) Usually the decision to use transposed-form is for high speed FPGA implementations with a large number of taps as you can eliminate a long adder tree which would otherwise limit the maximum clock frequency to a lower number due to the accumulated effect of multiplier and adder delay, but this can get more complicated for a fixed precision implementation since the bit width must grow as you proceed in the filter. (This consideration is particularly important in IIR implementations where feedback exists but affects FIR implementations with large adder trees, and also a reason to factor longer IIR filters in cascade form). At lower speeds the direct-form is more convenient to implement as you can use a single extended precision accumulator.

I include a summary of the basic forms applicable to FIR/IIR below for benefit of readers that may be less familiar, and see link from Ben in the comments for more advanced structures specific to FPGA implementations:

[image: Direct Form 1]

[image: Direct Form 2]

[image: Tranposing Filters]

[image: Transposed From]

[image: Cascade From]

Comment: Thank you Sir, I am sorry, I just used the information from my lecture. Now it makes sense.

Comment: @EceSuIldiz I added some figures in case we are referring to different things

Comment: Yes I was talking about FIR, I also added some figures.

Comment: @EceSuIldiz Nice, thank you. Notice there are the same number of memory elements and computations? There is no need to keep a buffer of the output of each of the adders in memory, just the final result (so in the direct form 1 the right side represents a single accumulator of each of the scaled and delayed outputs).  The time to accumulate everything may be limited, in which case the transposed form is convenient since it can all be done at once in synchronous fashion (good structure in an FPGA to have a synchronous element at the output of every adder versus accumulating delays.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.

Comment: For IIR filters implemented in FPGAs, adder trees delay don't matter much. Multiplier delays are the biggest performance killers. Hence techniques like "scattered-look-ahead" and "IIR parallelization"

http://people.ece.umn.edu/users/parhi/SLIDES/chap10.pdf

Comment: @Ben thanks for the link. We can treat the transposed form as a solution to the effects of the combination of both computational delays which would otherwise accumulate (and be a particular problem in feedback structures). [I clarified my answer that the adder tree accumulates both multiplier and adder delay thanks to your comment)

Comment: sorry Dan, but i had to downvote this answer.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson what did I say that you feel is not accurate? The first sentence or other content?

Comment: // *I don't see how memory or computational burden can possibly be reduced between the two implementations.* //  it's not inaccurate because it is how you see it.  but how you see it is mistaken.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson not sure I agree--- to avoid quantization error subsequent stages  increase in precision which is what I stated but this does not increase the computational burden-- I think you might be looking at it from a software implementation model rather than FPGA (there is not necessarily a concept of fixed width precision in the FPGA).

Comment: you can have a ***single*** accumulator that has double-wide word width with the Direct Form and all of the states are single-width words.  with the Transposed Form, either you must have all of your states have double-width words or you must quantize each state and you'll have $M+1$ quantizations instead of just one.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson it pinged me to do that-- what i wrote there was that you would quantize each state and the quantization would increase such that you do not get any additional quantization noise growth (similar to the extended precision accumulator). You do NOT need a double-width word at the output of each adder but add an additional bit after every doubling of the number of adds-- then truncate the final stage to your output precision thus adding that q-noise once at the output. So whether you use a single accumulator or distribute the adding does not change the # of computations.

Comment: whether it's hardware FPGA or a Mot 56K or a SHArC, the principles are the same.  with Direct Form FIR, all you need is the added complexity of a ***single*** double-wide accumulator and you suffer ***no*** quantization error until the very last casting of the output $y[n]$ to the same word width as the input $x[n]$.  that cannot be said for the Transposed Form.  for the latter, either you must have double-wide words for each state or you must have $M+1$ quantizations instead of just one.  I would prefer to have ***both*** simplicity and to minimize the quantization error.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Agree totally on complexity which I detailed in the answer. Although that doesn't impact the computation and memory burden which was my first sentence. So just not convinced (yet) my first sentence is really in error. Everything else you are saying is exactly what I wrote in that first paragraph

Comment: so now Dan, consider the OP.  Why do FIR implementations more often use Direct Form instead of Transposed Form?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Which is what I wrote--- I suspect you read the first sentence and associated computation burden with complexity but didn't read my full answer? (Granted I am not known for brevity)

Answer (score 1):

if the implementation preserves bits until quantization **must** occur at the final output, the Direct Form is far simpler than the Transposed Form.  using the transposed form requires that your states have double-wide word widths unless you quantize each of those states back to single width.  but that is more quantization error than if you just add up a bunch of double-wide words and quantize the result.